# Python file handling - will buffer definitely be flushed before exit?

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following python script:

```
with open(fileName, "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write(myData)
```

I don't really know how file buffers work, but I am aware of the fact that characters may queue up and not actually be written to file immediately.

My question is: once the python script ends, will the file DEFINITELY contain myData? I.e., if I'm calling this from the command line as `python script.py`, then when I get control again at the command line, will the file reflect my changes 100% of the time?

If it matters (maybe this is specific to the filesystem used?), I'll be running this on a 64-bit Windows machine (running Windows 7).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  It is actually flushed on close which is guaranteed to happen when you leave your `with` block.

Comment: Well, it's not quite _definitely_. If you force-quit the process before Python can interpret the end of the `with` block, or some other thread causes a crash, or this is inside a daemon thread and the main thread finishes, or… But it's as close as you can get to definitely; any normal exit (including raising an exception, calling `sys.exit`, etc.) will go through the `with` block.

Comment: True. On a process killed, it will not flush the buffer but then it never really left the with block did it.  It just ended the process as is.

Comment: That's a great way to look at it. It's guaranteed to happen when _the interpreter_ leaves the `with` block. Since "the process leaves the `with` block" doesn't really mean anything, that keeps everything nice and simple. Much clearer than my explanation.